# python None object

Tags: python, arrays

could you please explain what do I get in python with this lines? What does this code creates?

```
 NP = 2
 NB = 2  
 ND = 2 

 N  = NP*NB*ND 
 M  = 2*N + NP*NB
 res =  [[None] * 3] * (M)
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What happens when you run this code? Please update your question with the output.

Comment: It creates a list which contains another list (`[None, None, None]`) twenty times.

Comment: Is your question related to how multiplication on lists work?

Comment: run it, print it, and you'll see

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you actually run the code, you get

```
>>> res
[[None, None, None], [None, None, None], [None, None, None], [None, None, None], [None, None, None], [None, None, None], [None, None, None], [None, None, None], [None, None, None], [None, None, None], [None, None, None], [None, None, None], [None, None, None], [None, None, None], [None, None, None], [None, None, None], [None, None, None], [None, None, None], [None, None, None], [None, None, None]]
```

However, it's worth knowing that the lists within the top-level list are actually a single list repeated several times, so mutating one mutates all of them:

```
>>> res[0][1] = 'x'
>>> res
[[None, 'x', None], [None, 'x', None], [None, 'x', None], [None, 'x', None], [None, 'x', None], [None, 'x', None], [None, 'x', None], [None, 'x', None], [None, 'x', None], [None, 'x', None], [None, 'x', None], [None, 'x', None], [None, 'x', None], [None, 'x', None], [None, 'x', None], [None, 'x', None], [None, 'x', None], [None, 'x', None], [None, 'x', None], [None, 'x', None]]
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I am new in python, so it was unclear for me how it creates the empty list inside the other list, but now I get it.